# How to use Python3 named arguments and optional arguments at the same time

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

Given:

```py
def named_args_with_optional_args(arg1, arg2, *optional_args, kwarg1=1, kwarg2=1):
    pass
```

Both of these work:

```py
named_args_with_optional_args(arg1=1, arg2=1,**{"kwarg1":1,"kwarg2":1})  # all args named, no optional args
named_args_with_optional_args(1, 1, *(1,2,3), **{"kwarg1":1,"kwarg2":1}) # optional args used, *but no named args*
```

However, how can I call `named_args_with_optional_args` using both named arguments and optional arguments at the same time? I've tried:

```py
named_args_with_optional_args(arg1=1,arg2=1, *(1,2,3), **{"kwarg1":1,"kwarg2":1})  # TypeError: named_args_with_optional_args() got multiple values for argument 'arg1'
named_args_with_optional_args(arg1=1,arg2=1, optional_args=(1,2,3), **{"kwarg1":1,"kwarg2":1})  # TypeError: named_args_with_optional_args() got an unexpected keyword argument 'optional_args'
named_args_with_optional_args(arg1=1,arg2=1, 1,2,3, **{"kwarg1":1,"kwarg2":1})  # SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
named_args_with_optional_args(arg1=1,arg2=1, *optional_args=(1,2,3), **{"kwarg1":1,"kwarg2":1})  # SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: You can do `def named_args_with_optional_args(*optional_args, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=1, kwarg2=1):` and `named_args_with_optional_args(1, 2, 3, arg1=4, arg2=5, kwarg1=6, kwarg2=7)`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have `*optional_args` first:

```
def named_args_with_optional_args(*optional_args, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=1, kwarg2=1):
    print('optional_args', optional_args)
    print('arg1', arg1)
    print('arg2', arg2)
    print('kwarg1', kwarg1)
    print('kwarg2', kwarg2)
```

then

```
named_args_with_optional_args(1,2,3, arg1=4, arg2=5, **{"kwarg1":6,"kwarg2":7})
```

will work

```
optional_args (1, 2, 3)
arg1 4
arg2 5
kwarg1 6
kwarg2 7
```

However, this will force  you to pass `arg1` and `arg2` as kwargs since Python can't know when `*optional_args` end.

```
named_args_with_optional_args(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, **{"kwarg1":6,"kwarg2":7})
```

will **not** work.

Comment: Ty for the quick response @DeepSpace! Unfortunately, I'm using an [already defined API](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/serve/package-ref.html#ray.serve.create_backend).